# Why is the MongoDB aggregate function not working on the local machine?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

As shown below, I'm trying to group data from my MongoDB database, which is present locally on my machine.

```
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config();

let uri = process.env.MongoConnectionString;
let client = new MongoClient(uri);

let database = client.db('users');
let coll = database.collection('doctors');

async function run(){
  let data = await coll.aggregate([
    {
      $group:{
        _id:"$specialization",
        name:{$first:"$username"},
        imgsrc:{$first:"$ProfileImg"}
      }
    }
  ])
  console.log(data);
}
run();
```

Output was supposed to be an array of 12 objects, each having 3 fields(_id, name,imgsrc).
On executing the code, I'm getting a response like this:

```
<ref *2> AggregationCursor {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(client)]: MongoClient {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    mongoLogger: MongoLogger {
      error: [Function: bound log],
      warn: [Function: bound log],
      info: [Function: bound log],
      debug: [Function: bound log],
      trace: [Function: bound log],
      componentSeverities: [Object],
      maxDocumentLength: 1000,
      logDestination: [Object]
    },
    s: {
      url: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000',
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace],
      hasBeenClosed: false,
      sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
      activeSessions: [Set],
      options: [Getter],
      readConcern: [Getter],
      writeConcern: [Getter],
      readPreference: [Getter],
      isMongoClient: [Getter]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      hosts: [Array],
      compressors: [Array],
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      directConnection: true,
      driverInfo: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000,
      loadBalanced: false,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      maxConnecting: 2,
      maxIdleTimeMS: 0,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
      minPoolSize: 0,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      monitorCommands: false,
      noDelay: true,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 2000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      srvMaxHosts: 0,
      srvServiceName: 'mongodb',
      waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0,
      zlibCompressionLevel: 0,
      dbName: 'test',
      userSpecifiedAuthSource: false,
      userSpecifiedReplicaSet: false,
      mongoLoggerOptions: [Object],
      metadata: [Object],
      [Symbol(@@mdb.enableMongoLogger)]: false
    }
  },
  [Symbol(namespace)]: MongoDBCollectionNamespace { db: 'users', collection: 'doctors' },
  [Symbol(id)]: null,
  [Symbol(documents)]: List {
    count: 0,
    head: <ref *1> {
      next: [Circular *1],
      prev: [Circular *1],
      value: null
    }
  },
  [Symbol(initialized)]: false,
  [Symbol(closed)]: false,
  [Symbol(killed)]: false,
  [Symbol(options)]: {
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    useBigInt64: false,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    raw: false,
    enableUtf8Validation: true
  },
  [Symbol(session)]: ClientSession {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { ended: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      mongoLogger: [MongoLogger],
      s: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    sessionPool: ServerSessionPool { client: [MongoClient], sessions: [List] },
    hasEnded: false,
    clientOptions: [Object: null prototype] {
      hosts: [Array],
      compressors: [Array],
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      directConnection: true,
      driverInfo: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000,
      loadBalanced: false,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      maxConnecting: 2,
      maxIdleTimeMS: 0,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
      minPoolSize: 0,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      monitorCommands: false,
      noDelay: true,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 2000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      srvMaxHosts: 0,
      srvServiceName: 'mongodb',
      waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0,
      zlibCompressionLevel: 0,
      dbName: 'test',
      userSpecifiedAuthSource: false,
      userSpecifiedReplicaSet: false,
      mongoLoggerOptions: [Object],
      metadata: [Object],
      [Symbol(@@mdb.enableMongoLogger)]: false
    },
    explicit: false,
    supports: { causalConsistency: false },
    clusterTime: undefined,
    operationTime: undefined,
    owner: [Circular *2],
    defaultTransactionOptions: {},
    transaction: Transaction {
      state: 'NO_TRANSACTION',
      options: {},
      _pinnedServer: undefined,
      _recoveryToken: undefined
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(snapshotEnabled)]: false,
    [Symbol(serverSession)]: null,
    [Symbol(txnNumberIncrement)]: 0
  },
  [Symbol(pipeline)]: [ { '$group': [Object] } ],
  [Symbol(options)]: {
    raw: false,
    useBigInt64: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    ignoreUndefined: false,
    bsonRegExp: false,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    fieldsAsRaw: {},
    enableUtf8Validation: true,
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

- I tried printing the `uri` variable to check whether environment variables are getting accessed as expected. It gave me the local connection string as expected.
- I also tried executing the same command in `mongosh`, which gives me the exact 12 objects as needed.

Please guide me if there is any error in the above code. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the cursor object into a JavaScript array using `toArray()`

Following would be your modified code:

```js
let { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config();

let uri = process.env.MongoConnectionString;
let client = new MongoClient(uri);

let database = client.db('users');
let coll = database.collection('doctors');

async function run(){
  let data = await coll.aggregate([
    {
      $group:{
        _id:"$specialization",
        name:{$first:"$username"},
        imgsrc:{$first:"$ProfileImg"}
      }
    }
  ]);

  // convert the aggregate cursor to js array
  let dataAsArray = await data.toArray();

  console.log(dataAsArray);
}
run();
```

You can find more about this [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-get-aggregation-pipeline-result-in-a-route-get-in-node-js/140163)